# Taking a screenshot from one of the Camera GameObjects when the game is running and then output

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to make a game in which the player can take a picture of the view in one of the camera GameObjects whilst the game is running and then save that image and view it later in the same play session, much like taking a screenshot using a camera item in other games and then viewing it in a gallery. I was wondering if there was currently anyway of doing this within Unity as it will be a central mechanic in my game.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this.

The simplest is `Application.CaptureScreenshot`, which will create an image file. To explore the screenshots, use a file explorer package, or implement your own.

The other solution is to use a `RenderTexture` and to export the data to a List. You can then create an UI to explore the List. The problem is that each texture will be uncompressed and kept in memory, which can become dangerously heavy after only a few screenshots. Only do this if you don't have access to files or if you only keep the last few screenshots.